# How can I identify sub-groups that exist within a set of similar groups?

Tags: sql, database, data-manipulation

I have a medium-sized list of permissions, and users assigned to those permissions.  I want to group users together into roles when they share the same permissions, but I'm running into some issues.

Manipulating the data in a spreadsheet, I'm able to calculate each unique set of permissions and group users together into a role based on their entire set of permissions.  The result of this is that each user is in only a single role.

What I'd like to be able to do is identify sub-groups in the data set so I can potentially reduce the number of roles, while increasing the number of role assignments per user.

Here's an example data set:
[image]

Looking at the data it's easy to find potential roles (User 1 and 2 both share the first 6 permissions), but is there a way to tease this type of data out through SQL, spreadsheet functions, or a simple program?

I realize there are multiple answers to this question based on minimum numbers of permissions per role, or minimum number of users assigned to a role, etc.

I'm not expecting to find a final answer, but trying to move an algorithmic step forward if that makes any sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than clustering (which is really bad on binary data) use either:

- **link prediction / recommender systems**: if user A has permissions b and c, what other permissions to suggest?
- **frequent itemset mining / association rules**: if user has a, b then he should also have permission c `a, b -> c`

Comment: Did a little digging on these theories, they are incredibly fascinating, however, I think they're much too advanced for my little data set.

Comment: (Missed my editing window)
Thanks for the info,  I suppose I was hoping for a simple algorithm that you could just feed in 2 groups and their associations and get a variety of possible ways to most efficiently categorize these associations.  I think what I'll do is simply try to visualize these relationships in a large grid and manually group similar users close to each other in the grid, and then create the groups by hand.

Comment: After doing a little more reading I stumbled upon this amazing [library](http://www.philippe-fournier-viger.com/spmf/index.php?link=documentation.php#example1) which does exactly what I need.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, lets make some data!

```
DECLARE @User TABLE
(
    Perm INT,
    User1 INT,
    User2 INT,
    User3 INT,
    User4 INT,
    User5 INT,
    User6 INT,
    User7 INT,
    User8 INT,
    User9 INT,
    User10 INT
)

INSERT INTO @User
( Perm, User1, User2, User3, User4, User5, User6, User7, User8, User9, User10 )
VALUES
( 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 ),
( 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1 ),
( 3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ),
( 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ),
( 5, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1 ),
( 6, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1 ),
( 7, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1 ),
( 8, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ),
( 9, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1 );
```

Now we have the permissions and users in a table, now we do some bit counting and make a grouping value.

```
SELECT
    u.Perm,
    u.User1, 
    u.User2, 
    u.User3, 
    u.User4, 
    u.User5, 
    u.User6, 
    u.User7, 
    u.User8, 
    u.User9, 
    u.User10,
    CASE WHEN u.User1 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
    CASE WHEN u.User2 = 1 THEN 2 ELSE 0 END +
    CASE WHEN u.User3 = 1 THEN 4 ELSE 0 END +
    CASE WHEN u.User4 = 1 THEN 8 ELSE 0 END +
    CASE WHEN u.User5 = 1 THEN 16 ELSE 0 END +
    CASE WHEN u.User6 = 1 THEN 32 ELSE 0 END +
    CASE WHEN u.User7 = 1 THEN 64 ELSE 0 END +
    CASE WHEN u.User8 = 1 THEN 128 ELSE 0 END +
    CASE WHEN u.User9 = 1 THEN 256 ELSE 0 END +
    CASE WHEN u.User10 = 1 THEN 512 ELSE 0 END AS GroupMe
FROM @User u
```

Here is the output:

```
Perm    User1   User2   User3   User4   User5   User6   User7   User8   User9   User10  GroupMe
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1023
2   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   899
3   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
4   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   15
5   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   899
6   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   771
7   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   0   1   1   892
8   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
9   1   0   1   1   0   1   1   0   1   1   877
```

You'll see that 3 and 8 have the same value.
Also 2 and 5 have the same value.

Ok, lets add a perm breakout area using a numbers table:

```
;WITH
a AS (SELECT 1 AS i UNION ALL SELECT 1),
b AS (SELECT 1 AS i FROM a AS x, a AS y),
c AS (SELECT 1 AS i FROM b AS x, b AS y),
d AS (SELECT 1 AS i FROM c AS x, c AS y),
e AS (SELECT 1 AS i FROM d AS x, d AS y),
f AS (SELECT 1 AS i FROM e AS x, e AS y),
numbers AS 
(
    SELECT TOP(10)
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS number
    FROM f
), PrivBreakout AS
(
    SELECT 1 AS UserId, u.Perm 
    FROM @User u
    WHERE u.User1 = 1
    UNION
    SELECT 2 AS UserId, u.Perm 
    FROM @User u
    WHERE u.User2 = 1
    UNION
    SELECT 3 AS UserId, u.Perm 
    FROM @User u
    WHERE u.User3 = 3
    UNION
    SELECT 4 AS UserId, u.Perm 
    FROM @User u
    WHERE u.User4 = 1
    UNION
    SELECT 5 AS UserId, u.Perm 
    FROM @User u
    WHERE u.User5 = 1
    UNION
    SELECT 6 AS UserId, u.Perm 
    FROM @User u
    WHERE u.User6 = 1
    UNION
    SELECT 7 AS UserId, u.Perm 
    FROM @User u
    WHERE u.User7 = 1
    UNION
    SELECT 8 AS UserId, u.Perm 
    FROM @User u
    WHERE u.User8 = 1
    UNION
    SELECT 9 AS UserId, u.Perm 
    FROM @User u
    WHERE u.User9 = 1
    UNION
    SELECT 10 AS UserId, u.Perm 
    FROM @User u
    WHERE u.User10 = 1
), ThreeLayerCombo AS
(
    SELECT 
        a.number AS priva,
        b.number AS privb,
        c.number AS privc
    FROM numbers a
    CROSS JOIN numbers b
    CROSS JOIN numbers c
    WHERE b.number > a.number
        AND c.number > b.number
)
```

Now in the code above, I decided to look for combinations of at least 3 permissions

```
SELECT t.priva, t.privb, t.privc, COUNT(DISTINCT a.UserId) AS Grouper
FROM ThreeLayerCombo t
INNER JOIN PrivBreakout a
    ON t.priva = a.Perm
INNER JOIN PrivBreakout b
    ON b.UserId = a.UserId
    AND t.privb = b.Perm
INNER JOIN PrivBreakout c
    ON c.UserId = a.UserId
    AND t.privc = c.Perm
GROUP BY t.priva, t.privb, t.privc
ORDER BY COUNT(DISTINCT a.UserId) DESC
```

Lets look for the best combos, here is the output:

```
priva   privb   privc   Grouper
1   2   5   5
1   7   9   5
2   5   6   4
1   2   6   4
1   5   6   4
1   2   9   3
2   5   9   3
1   5   9   3
1   6   9   3
2   6   9   3
5   6   9   3
5   7   9   2
5   6   7   2
4   5   6   2
2   7   9   2
6   7   9   2
1   4   9   2
1   6   7   2
2   6   7   2
2   5   7   2
2   4   5   2
2   4   6   2
1   2   7   2
1   5   7   2
1   2   4   2
1   4   5   2
1   4   6   2
1   4   7   1
1   4   8   1
1   2   3   1
1   5   8   1
1   2   8   1
1   3   4   1
1   3   5   1
1   3   6   1
1   3   8   1
1   3   9   1
2   4   8   1
2   4   9   1
2   5   8   1
2   6   8   1
1   6   8   1
1   8   9   1
2   3   4   1
2   3   5   1
2   3   6   1
2   3   8   1
2   3   9   1
6   8   9   1
2   8   9   1
3   4   5   1
3   4   6   1
3   4   8   1
3   4   9   1
3   5   6   1
3   5   8   1
3   5   9   1
3   6   8   1
3   6   9   1
3   8   9   1
4   5   8   1
4   5   9   1
4   6   8   1
4   6   9   1
4   7   9   1
4   8   9   1
5   6   8   1
5   8   9   1
```

From the output the best bets are (1, 2, 5) and (1, 7, 9) to build specific roles against.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Kevin, this is actually the same method I used to create my original groups.  My goal is to find common sub-groups.  In this solution, every user is the member of exactly one group / role, when in reality, they are likely part of multiple smaller groups of permissions / roles.